# Expected 'not' in if statement template error

Tags: django, facebook, django-templates

In my page I have a voting possibility. Each object can be liked with facebook 'Like' button. If item is already liked, I would like to hide the button. So I've wrote a method for liked object's to check if user with given ip already voted. IP is stored in context variable.

```
def check_vote(self, ip):
    id = self.id
    logging.debug("id: %s, ip: %s" % (id, ip))
    try:
        voted = Vote.objects.get(uid=id, ip=ip)
        return False
    except:
        logging.debug("returning True")
        return True
```

Here's my view:

```
def artifact_finalists(request):           
    submissions = ArtifactSubmission.objects.filter(resized=True, final=True)
    template_name = 'rte/artifact_finalists.html'
    return render_to_response(template_name, {"submissions": submissions, 'voting': voting,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And template:

```
    {% for submission in submissions %}
        <li style="float:left, width:400px, margin-right:20px">
            <div class="single-submission">
                <div style="float:left, margin-right:10px">
                    <img src="{{ submission.url100 }}" width="100px" />
                </div>
                <div style="float:left">
                    <span style="float:left">{{ submission.name }}</span>
                    <span style="float:left">{{ submission.description }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="vote">
                    {% if submission.get_vote IP_ADDRESS %}
                        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like layout="button_count" href="http://ntt.vipserv.org{{submission.get_absolute_url}}"></fb:like>
                    {% endif %}                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

But it raises : `Expected 'not' in if statement` . Any ideas why ? Adding 'not' in 'if' tag raises `improperly formatted` :/

Comment: solved with custom filter, will post it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement in the template seems to be missing an operator.

```
{% if submission.get_vote IP_ADDRESS %}
```

if submission.get_vote (is what to the) IP_ADDRESS? == perhaps?

See the [Django template docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#boolean-operators) for a list of what `if` accepts in a template.

Also, it's not clear what IP_ADDRESS is. Do you mean REMOTE_ADDR, or to somehow refer to the ip address you have already?

Also, I'd suggest not using a bare `except:`. Limit it to the exceptions you are thinking of specifically. Not specifying the exception can hide other errors. I suggest adding

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

and then

```
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
```

in the check_vote method.

Where is check_vote called?

Comment: goddamn it seems I misspelled it :/ got it working still thanks for help.